# Profile picture in iOS app

Tags: support, bug, ios-app, profile-picture

Recently I changed my profile picture for ruSO account only. I see the changes in iOS app:

> [image: ruSO]

When I switch to another site, eg MetaSE, I see no changes in app left menu, but old picture in profile:

> [image: mse]

Is it normal behavior (using picture from the site where I earned more rep) or icon from the left menu should be consistent with current site profile picture?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)